Is there a way to deploy the AWS Liveness service in Flutter?
I am currently working on a Flutter application that requires the use of a Liveness service, I had planned to use the AWS service, but I have not found information that guarantees that it will be possible. I would like to know if anyone has found a way to implement it, either directly or through an intermediary. Any suggestions are welcome.

https://pub.dev/packages/aws_rekognition_api

Excuse me, this package includes the liveness service api?

/// This API operation initiates a Face Liveness session. It returns a
/// SessionId, which you can use to start streaming Face Liveness
/// video and get the results for a Face Liveness session.

I got it, thank you. I just have one more question, does this package have any documentation? I say this because I have not been able to find anything like it on the page.

https://pub.dev/documentation/aws_rekognition_api/latest/rekognition-2016-06-27/ Use that in conjunction with the AWS developer guide

I've been reading the documentation, but I haven't found anything that would allow me to perform a liveness test (the closest thing it has is facial detection). Are you sure this package contains what I need?

No, of course I'm not sure. However, since this library is a wrapper of the REST API then if the REST API supports it you might be able to use it. If the definitions are out of date, you could ask the package provider to update it to the latest API and/or simply use it as a model of how to call the REST API yourself.

Ok, i got it. Thank you so much for the information
